# RNN raising error for most datasets, "`start_index+length=7 > end_index=4` is disallowed"

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, valueerror

So I'm creating a frame AI network to predict substantial outbreaks throughout the world. The first step of my process is predicting factor data over the next couple of years. So far, I've been calling a function to make my models and saving them as different files. I've stored my data in the same file to make it easier. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as kr
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
import math
def AIcooker(name_of_the_pdf, number_of_epochs, vertical_length_of_set, horizontal_length_of_set, splitting_percentage, window_size, time_horizon, i_var):
    water = pd.read_csv(
    name_of_the_pdf,
    parse_dates = True,
    index_col = 'Date'
    )
    water = water.drop('Date.1', axis = 1)
    warray = water.values

    water.replace([np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan], 0, inplace=True)
    
    nom = math.floor(vertical_length_of_set*splitting_percentage)

    train = water.iloc[:nom]
    test = water.iloc[nom:]
    
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaler.fit(train)
    scaler_train = scaler.transform(train)
    scaler_test = scaler.transform(test)
    
    n_input = window_size
    n_features = horizontal_length_of_set
    generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaler_train, scaler_train, length = n_input, batch_size = 1)
    
    X, y = generator[0]
    X.shape
    
    model = kr.Sequential()
    model.add(kr.layers.Reshape((n_input, n_features)))
    model.add(LSTM(512, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (n_input, n_features)))
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Dense(n_features))
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse')
    
    i = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor=i_var,
        patience=20,
        restore_best_weights=True,
        verbose = 1
    )
    model.fit(generator, epochs = number_of_epochs, callbacks = [i])
    
    last_trained_batch = scaler_train[-n_input:]
    last_trained_batch = last_trained_batch.reshape((1, n_input, n_features))
    c = model.predict(last_trained_batch)
    
    test_predictions = []
    first_eval_batch = scaler_train[-n_input:]
    current_batch = first_eval_batch.reshape((1, n_input, n_features))
    
    for i in range(time_horizon):  # Iterate for the specified time horizon
        current_pred = model.predict(current_batch)[0]
        test_predictions.append(current_pred)
        current_batch = np.append(current_batch[:, 1:, :], [[current_pred]], axis=1)

    
    ui = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predictions)
    print(ui)

    return model, ui
""" model1, ui1 = AIcooker('HI - HI.csv', 10000, 23, 130, 0.9, 8, 100, 'loss')
model1.save('WaterQuality.keras')
np.savetxt('WaterQualityResults.txt', ui1, fmt='%.18f')
model2, ui2 = AIcooker('yy.csv', 10000, 30, 192, 0.8, 7, 100, 'loss')
model2.save('PD.keras')
np.savetxt('PDResults.txt', ui2, fmt='%.18f') 
model3, ui3 = AIcooker('34.csv', 3000, 22, 192, 0.8, 7, 100, 'loss')
model3.save('P.keras')
np.savetxt('PResults.txt', ui3, fmt='%.18f')"""
'''model4, ui4 = AIcooker('0-4.csv', 5000, 71, 236, 0.8, 7, 100, 'val_loss')
model4.save('0-4.keras')
np.savetxt('0-4Results.txt', ui4, fmt='%.18f')'''
model5, ui5 = AIcooker('6.csv', 5000, 7, 126, 0.8, 7, 100, 'loss')
model5.save('0-0.keras')
np.savetxt('0-0Results.txt', ui5, fmt='%.18f')
```

So now my issue:

With most of the data, it gives me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\fatim\Videos\PredictAI\WarterqualityAI.py", line 87, in <module>
    model5, ui5 = AIcooker('6.csv', 5000, 7, 126, 0.8, 7, 100, 'loss')
  File "c:\Users\fatim\Videos\PredictAI\WarterqualityAI.py", line 35, in AIcooker
    generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaler_train, scaler_train, length = n_input, batch_size = 1)
  File "C:\Users\fatim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\preprocessing\sequence.py", line 158, in __init__  
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: `start_index+length=7 > end_index=4` is disallowed, as no part of the sequence would be left to be used as current step.
```

I'm confused what this means.

Thank you to anyone who helps!